# Using PowerShell to get a count from a csv file and export to csv

Tags: powershell, csv, import, export

I have a csv file with name,id,age. I have imported it properly and am looking for a count of all names that are null(empty). 
I have this so far:

```
@(Import-Csv C:\Mine\Desktop\f1.txt | Where-Object {$_.name -eq ""}).Count
```

This prints out the correct number of empty names into the prompt, but if I export it, nothing shows up in the txt file.

```
@(Import-Csv C:\Mine\Desktop\f1.txt | Where-Object {$_.name -eq ""}).Count | Export-Csv C:\Mine\Desktop\tests.txt -notype
```

So it shows the correct number in the command prompt, but when I try to export it, it creates the .txt but it is empty. Any help would be appreciated. Also, if I wanted to know how many null entries their are in the entire CSV (from name,id,age). Would the best way be to do this line
`Where-Object {$_.name -eq ""}` but change `$_.name` every time? Or is there a shorter version?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are taking an integer (the count of entries with blank names) and trying to export a CSV. `Export-CSV` expects you to have an object, or array of objects with properties that it can convert to a table in CSV format, with property names as the header row, and values below that for each object.

What you want is to just output that value to a file, so try replacing `Export-CSV` with `Set-Content` (and remove the `-notype`) to set the content of the file you specify to the number delivered by your command.

Comment: Depending if the file already contains data `Add-Content` might be considered a better fit. OP made no indication either way but its worth noting. Don't see exporting a file with just a number being useful.